# Handling the Host names, Subject Alternative names in certificate

Tags: openssl, x509

How exactly should Host names be compared in an x509 certificate?

eg: if the certificate is registered for `*.abcorp.com`, then can a site like `www.sales.abcorp.com` be valid for this certificate? or only sites like `sales.abcorp.com` be valid in such a case?

This question is to clear a doubt in my mind on my implementation of hostname check for ssl certificate.

Google Chrome goes with the later. i.e if a certificate has CN field as `*.abcorp.com`, then only sites like `sales.abcorp.com` will be valid under that certificate and sites like `www.sales.abcorp.com` will throw an error saying servers certificate doesnot match the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such certificates are known as Wildcard certificate. After reading about wildcard certificate at [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate), it is found that only single level of sub-domain matching is supported.

Since supporting www over domain may accidentally support multiple levels of domain.
Therefore, cases such as www.sales.abcorp.com does not match.